# bcp error: date invalid date format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, csv, bcp

I'm a `bcp` newbie. I want to insert a large file. I'm having a hard time uploading `datetime` format.

Table SQL:

```
"Create Table dbo.my_test ( " + \
    "transaction_id BIGINT ," + \
    "transaction_no INT ," + \
    "store_no INT ," + \
    "register_no INT ," + \
    "transaction_date DATETIME," + \
    ");"
```

My csv file:

```
"771666690","346138","400","1","2015-06-18 00:00:00"
```

My format file:

```
13.0
6
1       SQLBIGINT           0       8       "\""      0     test_                                                       ""
2       SQLBIGINT           0       8       "\",\""   1     transaction_id                                                       ""
3       SQLINT              0       4       "\",\""   2     transaction_no                                                       ""
4       SQLINT              0       4       "\",\""   3     store_no                                                             ""
5       SQLINT              0       4       "\",""   4     register_no                                                          ""
6       SQLDATETIME         0       8       "\r\n"   5     transaction_date                                                     ""
```

My bcp command:

```
>bcp data_base.dbo.my_test in "test.csv" -f "test.fmt" -S localhost -U *** -P *****
```

Output

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1
```

I am using SQL Server 2016. Default language is csv.

---

I slimmed down the type just to get a toy example up, here is the new scripts:

Table SQL:

```
"Create Table dbo.my_test ( " + \
    "transaction_date DATETIME," + \
    ");"
```

My csv file:

```
2015-06-18
```

My bcp command:

```
>bcp data_base.dbo.my_test in "test.csv" -f "test.fmt" -S localhost -U *** -P *****
```

Output:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `bcp` format file has six columns defined, but the csv dataset and table have only five columns.

I was able to import your sample data successfully using the format file:

```
14.0
5
1       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ",\""     1     transaction_id      ""
2       SQLINT          0       4       "\",\""   2     transaction_no      ""
3       SQLINT          0       4       "\",\""   3     store_no            ""
4       SQLINT          0       4       "\",\""   4     register_no         ""
5       SQLDATETIME     0       8       "\"\r\n"  5     transaction_date    ""
```

This works regardless of whether the table columns are `NULL` or `NOT NULL`, though it is good practice to always specify this in your `CREATE TABLE` statements to avoid ambiguity.

That said, importing csv data prior to SQL Server 2017 can be difficult, or even impossible. [From 2017 onward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#input-file-format-options), you can use the RFC 4180 compliant:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.my_test
FROM 'C:\Temp\my_test.csv'
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

See [Using the Bulk-Load Tools in SQL Server](http://sommarskog.se/bulkload.html) by Erland Sommarskog for a comprehensive description of the topic, including the special problems posed by csv data.